# Add field between two dates sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data that splits records up by month, but I want to collapse them into one continuous record from beginning to end date. I have the code that does that down, but I am not able to sum up the payments for that timeframe.

For example:

`PAYMENT   ID    STARTDATE    ENDDATE 
 3800      456  2016-02-21  2016-02-28
 1500      456  2016-09-01  2016-09-30
 12600     456  2016-10-01  2016-10-31
 12200     456  2016-11-01  2016-11-30
 3600      456  2016-12-01  2016-12-10`

I need the payment for the February record to stay the same, but the September-December records collapse into one, and I need the payment to be summed for those 4 rows.

This is the code I have so far

```
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY T.STARTDATE)       AS [ROW]
    INTO #TEMP2 
    FROM #FINALRECORDS    AS T 

   -- START DATES
   SELECT T.*
   , CASE
   WHEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,T.STARTDATE) = T1.ENDDATE
   THEN 0
   ELSE 1
   END AS [New]
   INTO #NEW
   FROM #TEMP2    AS T
   LEFT JOIN #TEMP2      AS T1  ON T.ID= T1.ID AND T.ROW = T1.ROW +1

   -- END DATES
   SELECT T.*
   , CASE
   WHEN DATEADD(DAY,1,T.ENDDATE) = T1.ENDDATE
   THEN 0
   ELSE 1
   END AS [End]
   INTO #END
   FROM #TEMP2    AS T
   LEFT JOIN #TEMP2      AS T1  ON T.ID= T1.ID AND T.ROW = T1.ROW -1

   -- SINGLE RECORD WITH START AND END DATE
   SELECT *
   FROM (
           SELECT T.*
           , T1.ENDDATE AS [NEW_DISCHAGE]
           , SUM(T.PAYMENT) AS [NEW_PAY]
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID, T.ROW ORDER BY T1.ENDDATE) AS [ROW2]
           FROM #NEW   AS T
           INNER JOIN #END    AS T1  ON T.ID= T1.ID AND T.ROW <= T1.ROW
           WHERE T.New = 1
           AND T1.[END] = 1

           GROUP BY T.ID, T.STARTDATE, T1.ENDDATE, T.ROW
   ) AS A
   WHERE A.ROW2 = 1
```

The output I'm looking for is somewhat like this:

`PAYMENT   ID    STARTDATE    ENDDATE 
 3800      456  2016-02-21  2016-02-28
 29900     456  2016-09-01  2016-09-30`

ETA: a better example

Comment: You need to provide us some details of your tables and data so we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want payment totals by year ?

```
create table #stuff (payment int, id int, startdate date, enddate date)

insert into #stuff values
 (3800,     456,  '2015-02-21','2015-02-28'),
 (1500,    456,  '2016-09-01','2016-09-30'),
 (12600,     456,  '2016-10-01','2016-10-31'),
 (12200,     456,  '2016-11-01','2016-11-30'),
 (3600,      456,  '2016-12-01','2016-12-10')


     select
    sum(payment) as payment,
    id,
    min(startdate) as startdate,
    max(enddate) as enddate
    from #stuff
    group by id, year(enddate)
```

Give this:

payment id  startdate   enddate

3800    456 2015-02-21  2015-02-28

29900   456 2016-09-01  2016-12-10

Comment: No, not by year, just by each encounter. And I can't enter the date values manually like that, as there are about 9000 more rows.

Comment: What manual entry do you mean ? the create table statement merely re-creates your example. Also - what do you mean by encounter ?